# Деплой SpringBoot приложения в embedded tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, embedded, war

Я создал простенькое SpringBoot приложение с Rest контроллером. Когда я запускаю его, все норм работает.
Хочется его деплоить кодом в томкате.
Собрал приложение в war`ку.
Создал отдельно проект для поднятия и деплоя этой варки:

```
public class TomcatLauncher
{
  public static void main(String aArgs[])
  {
    try
    {
      File catalinaHome = new File("путь"); 
      Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
      tomcat.setPort(8080);
      tomcat.setBaseDir(catalinaHome.getAbsolutePath());
      tomcat.getServer().addLifecycleListener(new VersionLoggerListener());

      File war = new File("путь до варки");
      tomcat.addWebapp("/boot", war.getAbsolutePath())

      tomcat.start();
      tomcat.getServer().await();

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Запускаю, выкидывает вот такой ексепшн, но все работает:

```
.. Запущен томкат тра-та-та 
запускаем спрингбут ... тратата .. 
2016-10-13 14:54:05.202  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-10-13 14:54:05.222  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.aamsystems.SpringBootTestApplication   : Started SpringBootTestApplication in 2.758 seconds (JVM running for 7.855)
2016-10-13 14:54:05.243  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/boot]   : Marking servlet jsp as unavailable
2016-10-13 14:54:05.248 ERROR 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/boot]   : Servlet [jsp] in web application [/boot] threw load() exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1284) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1061) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1000) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Если сделать addContext("/boot", war.getAbsolutePath()); вместо addWebApp, эксепшена нету, но и лога приложения собственно нету.

JSP страниц у меня нету и не будет.

Вопросы такие:

- Как убрать этот эксепшен?
- Правильный ли вообще я подход избрал для всего этого дела? В дальнейшем планируется создавать еще spring boot приложения в war
  файлы и динамически их деплоить кодом.

Зависимости у меня в проекте томката следующие:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}
```

В springBoot проекте в принципе такие же, но я так понимаю либы там должны быть `providedRuntime`

Меин класс приложения:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SpringBootTestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: У Spring Boot есть свой embedded Tomcat внутри. Вы точно хотите взять war-ник с Tomcat внутри и запустить его на другом Tomcat?

Comment: Если так сделать, то у меня каждое приложение будет поднимать себе по серваку, если захочу работать с несколькими приложениями, как я понимаю. Какая-то не очень хорошая схема по-моему

Comment: @iteracia это популяризируемый сейчас подход самодостаточных веб-приложений. В нем нет ничего принципиально плохого.

Comment: Как то мне сложно понять этот подход. Если сделать 1 приложение, ну может 2, каждый со своим серваком, то это я еще понимаю - можно развернуть их независимо, просто и быстро. Но если у меня будет 20-30 приложений\сервисов не больших и у КАЖДОГО будет по своему http серверу, так еще и с кучей конфигурационных объектов внутри, по-моему  это сильно неоправданная нагрузка на машину как минимум.

Comment: @iteracia если вы хотите 20-30 приложений на 1-2 серверах, то это не Embedded Tomcat. Ставите отдельный томкат, определяете в нем context-root с конфигом и направляете его на свой дескриптор, в котором указываете адрес war-архива приложения для деплоя.

Comment: @Maksim, Спасибо за  совет, а можно ссылку на примерчик \ доку по этому подходу?

Comment: @iteracia документацию можно начинать читать [отсюда](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html). А вообще постараюсь описать решение, которое мы использовали, в ответе ниже.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь как деполоить, отключая встроенный контейнер Spring Boot. Может пригодится. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328762/how-to-host-spring-boot-application-with-postgresql-on-the-could-jelastic/43370194#43370194

Answer (score 1):

Нам пришлось прибегнуть к следующему решению:

1. Скачиваем Tomcat в виде ZIP-архива на машину и распаковываем в рабочую директорию, например, `C:\project\runtime\apache-tomcat-8.0.32`
2. Создаем директорию `C:\project\webapp`, где будет размещен файл конфигурации context-root, и переносим в нее WAR-архив с приложением, допустим, `ROOT.war`
3. Создаем файл конфигурации `ROOT.xml` со следующим содержимым:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <Context
     docBase="C:/project/webapp/ROOT.war"
     override="false"
     reloadable="false"
     path=""
     useNaming="true"
     unpackWAR="false"
   >
     <Parameter name="spring.profiles.active" value="dev" override="true" />
     <Parameter name="spring.config.location" value="file:///C:/project/properties/" override="true" />
     <Parameter name="LOG_PATH" value="C:/project/logs/" override="false" />
   </Context>
   ```

Параметры servlet context опциональны.

4. В файле конфигурации сервера `conf\server.xml` необходимо изменить описание хоста следующим образом:

   ```
   <Host xmlBase="C:/project/webapp" appBase="" autoDeploy="true" name="yourproject.io" unpackWARs="false" deployXML="false"></Host>
   ```

И дальше это упражнение можно повторять для каждого приложения, которое будет расположено на своем хосте.

Comment: @iteracia не забывайте жать стрелочки, если ответ был полезен 

Comment: Я бы с радостью, у меня просто репутации 0

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на фичи которые предоставляет Spring Boot - http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/. Одна из которых, возможность создания самодостаточных приложений, если вам крайне важно деплоить вашу war-ку на external Tomcat, попробуйте использовать просто Spring а не Spring Boot.

Comment: Мне очень нравятся фичи
Provide opinionated 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven configuration
Automatically configure Spring whenever possible
Absolutely no code generation and no requirement for XML configuration

Может конечно я ошибаюсь, но если использовать просто спринг это надо будет описывать частично конфигурацию в xml файлах, чего я вообще никак не хочу. + банально 1 зависимость в файлах получше чем 10+, хотя бы глазу. То что бута особенность это самодостаточное приложение я понимаю, но это меня интересует только на стадии разработки.